# Python msgraph API, retrieve calendar for rooms

Tags: python, microsoft-graph-api

I am sitting with the new `Python` `msgraph` package and trying to navigate my way through the `Microsoft GraphAPI` but it seems I am missing something.

What I want to do:

1. Retrieve the list of meeting rooms (done)
2. Retrieve the calendar for those rooms for the last week to find booked meetings and their planned attendance (not working)

What I did so far:

1. Set up application credentials in Azure for the application with the `Bookings.Read.All Calendars.Read Calendars.ReadBasic.All Group.Read.All Place.Read.All User.Read` permissions.
2. Set up a `certificate` for logging in.
3. Login with `msgraph` using the `certificate` and get a list of rooms

What I need:

1. Get a calendar from each room in the list I retrieve for a specific period.

I found a tutorial that uses the `client.me` endpoint but it is not possible to read through for an application.

Does anyone know how to fix that? (get_schedule_for_room to get the calendar from the room ID or room email) as a application.

Here is the code so far:

```py
    #!/usr/bin/env python3
    
    import asyncio
    from msgraph.generated.models.room import Room
    from msgraph.generated.users.item.calendar.get_schedule.get_schedule_request_builder import GetScheduleRequestBuilder
    from msgraph.generated.users.item.calendar.get_schedule.get_schedule_post_request_body import GetSchedulePostRequestBody
    from msgraph import GraphServiceClient
    
    from azure.identity import DeviceCodeCredential, CertificateCredential, AuthorizationCodeCredential

    config = {
      'client_id': '<something>',
      'tenant_id': '<something>',
      'client_secret': '<something>',
      'authority': 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/<something>',
      'scope': ['https://graph.microsoft.com/.default'],
      'certificate_path': 'msal_crt_n_key.pem',
    }
    
    async def get_schedule_for_room(graph_client, room_id):
        result = await graph_client.users.by_user_id(room_id).calendar.events.get()
        # DOES NOT WORK
        return result
    
    async def get_rooms(graph_client):
        return await graph_client.places.graph_room.get()
    
    async def main():
        # azure.identity.aio
        print("Login using certificate")
        credential = CertificateCredential(
            tenant_id=config['tenant_id'],
            client_id=config['client_id'],
            certificate_path=config['certificate_path'])
    
        graph_client = GraphServiceClient(credential, config['scope']) # type: ignore
        print("Get list of rooms")
        rooms = await get_rooms(graph_client)
        print(f"Rooms: {rooms}")
    
        room_ids = [r.id for r in rooms.value]
        print(f"Rooms IDs: {room_ids}")
    
        for id_ in room_ids:
            # The part below does not work
            calendar = await get_schedule_for_room(graph_client, id_)
            print(calendars)
            print(type(calendars))
    
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to use room's `emailAddress` instead of the `id`. The `id` of the room returned by `graph_client.places.graph_room.get()` is no the same ss `id` of the room in the users collection.

Try to change this
room_ids = [r.id for r in rooms.value]
print(f"Rooms IDs: {room_ids}")

```
for id_ in room_ids:
    # The part below does not work
    calendar = await get_schedule_for_room(graph_client, id_)
    print(calendars)
    print(type(calendars))
```

to

```
room_emails = [r.emailAddress for r in rooms.value]
print(f"Rooms emails: {room_emails}")

for email_ in room_emails:
    events = await get_schedule_for_room(graph_client, email_)
    print(events)
    print(type(events))
```

Also there can be a company access policy limiting app access to specific mailboxes.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-limit-mailbox-access

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But how should I change the get_schedule_for_room() call? Because graph_client.users.by_user_id(room_email).calendar.events.get() does not exist (I get a NameError: name 'calendars' is not defined)

Comment: @Kodsama Maybe the error NameError: name 'calendars' is not defined is caused by the next line print(calendars). Probably the correct name is events not calendar/calendars